# Get Targeted Facebook Post on PAGE

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to Geo Target a feed post on a page (not profile). I've successfully created a post, however I cannot target the post to a specific country, city or language as said possible by the Facebook API documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

The API documentation states "The description field may contain a comma-separated lists of valid country, city and language if a Page's post targeting by location/language is specified".

Here is my code:

```
// post vars
$access_token = $_POST['access_token'];
$page_id = $_POST['page_id'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . '/feed';
$post_fields = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'message' => $message,
    'privacy' => '{ "description": "United States", "value": "CUSTOM" }'
);

// initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();

    // Set options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // URL to cURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);

    // execute cURL
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // return results
    echo json_encode($response);

// close Connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm receiving a #100 API error from Facebook:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include privacy.","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

As you can see by the above API response, it's saying that it is not possible to include the privacy type (aka targeting) if we're posting as a page. This is inconsistent with what Facebook has documented to be possible.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 0):

Read about your problem [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238365492903384)

> Posts made by a page do not have privacy settings, they're always visible to everyone unless targetted using the appropriate options.
>   Also, posts made via the API do not have a 'share' link in the same way that manually created posts do - this is intentional

**UPDATE**

This looks like a documentation bug. I have attached a screenshot of the old version of the docs. Try using "targeting" with the same location format as:[image]
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/adsapi/targeting_specs/

Comment: I wrote that comment, but it was refering to something else:
There is a 'targeting' option for page posts which shows that post only to users in specific demographics  (distinct from 'privacy') - there is however an open bug report about this not currently working